# Problematic if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element filled with div "message" elements and in case there are more than 20 elements I want to fade them slice(20).animate and execute the rest of the code in the finished function of animate, but in case there isn't more than 20 elements I would like to execute the remaining code straight away, how would the logic look in jquery?

Sorry for noobish question, I am not that familiar with jquery.

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
if ($(".info #future>center>div").length<20) {/*Skip straight to bunch of other code*/}
$(".info #future>center>div").slice(20).animate({opacity:0}, 500, function()
{
//Bunch of other code here
```

Now if I just use slice 20 when when there are less than 20 divs in the center element bunch of other code never gets executed.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Added code, sorry if wasn't clear enough

Comment: Post a [complete working example](http://sscce.org) which shows your problematic behaviour and compare it to your observed behaviour. (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: IIRC the `center` element has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip into a function expression defined elsewhere. You will have to make it a standalone function (that is assigned to a variable available in both places), and either call it or pass it as the callback:

```
function done() {
    //Bunch of other code here
}
var divs = $(".info #future>center>div");
if (divs.length < 20)
    done();
else
    divs.slice(20).animate({opacity:0}, 500, done);
```